# Route traffic on a port to specific instance (Amazon EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This seems like it should be fairly easy, but I'm having some trouble finding a specific answer.

What is the best way to route traffic from an Amazon EC2 load balancer to specific instances?

For example, I want traffic on port 22 to always go to instance 1, and traffic on 443 and 80 to go to instance 2. Can this be done using the load balancer? Or must it be done another way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that with an ELB.  ELB's do allow you to have multiple listeners, but pinning a specific Listened to port to a specific server kind of defeats the purpose of a load balancer.

To do what you want, really requires 2 ELB's.  Setup one for your HTTP traffic and another for your ssh traffic.  I find it a bit odd that you would be using a load balancer for ssh.  If it is simply to have a gateway into a VPC, you could instead use an actual gateway server for that purpose.

Comment: There are use cases for using a load balancer for ssh, such as to ensure that you always get a live backend from a pool without having to lookup the current IP/manually move a CNAME/EIP. AWS does offer other ways to handle that though, (I've set up an AWS Lambda function that monitors an autoscaling group of size 2 via SNS and keeps the Route53 round-robin RR up-to-date as instances are terminated/die.  Something similar can be done with Elastic IPs.)

Comment: @KarenB Makes sense in terms of a large cluster like the one you describe, although in this case given the simplicity of the requirement, I have to question whether this is an end-around an incomplete VPC setup.

Comment: I found a few things online that suggested you could set up listeners on a load balancer in this way, but couldn't see how to do it in the console. It doesn't need to be done with a load balancer, but I'm afraid I don't see how to do it using the VPC either.

Comment: With a vpc you have a couple of options.  One way is to use a "NAT gateway" machine, which I frequently use a micro instance to save costs and for small businesses works ok usually.  The documentation for doing this is here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html  You give that machine an IP and connect to it, then depending on your firewalling rules, will allow you to connect to machines inside your vpc.

Comment: You can pretty easily tunnel into your private machines using the gateway and don't even have to put private keys on your internal machines if you don't want to, by configuring agent forwarding:  https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/